# Is there a way to pass global environment variable in deploy war to container jenkins job build action?

Tags: tomcat, jenkins, deployment, containers, war

I'm using deploy war/ear to container to deploy me war files to the tomcat server. This build action is used in multiple jobs each configured with the same tomcat URL. Is there a way to declare that URL as a global parameter and use it in the job?

Comment: In Manage Jenkins > Configure System, there is a 'Global Properties' section where you can define environment variables that any Jenkins build can use -- is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Not precise, I defined a URL as global variable and I want to pass it as a parameter in a post build action(Deploy war/ear to container). I don't how to pass it there. While passing it as - ${VARIABLENAME} it's not accepting.